# Tabpanel child remove wont work in Bootstrap GWT

Tags: gwt, twitter-bootstrap

While Using Bootstrap for GWT, i tried to remove a tab(Child) from TabPanel(Parent) with remove function and it doesnt work.

Also i tried with TabPanel ->TabLink->TabPane combo too which doesnt help though

```
<b:TabPanel tabPosition="left" ui:field="tabPanel">
    <b:Tab  ui:field="tabA" heading="tabA"></b:Tab>
    <b:Tab  ui:field="tabB" heading="tabB"></b:Tab>
    <b:Tab  ui:field="tabC" heading="tabC"></b:Tab>
</b:TabPanel>

tabPanel.remove(tabA);//doesnt work
```

Any Idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reported this issue in their [GitHub Issues](https://github.com/gwtbootstrap/gwt-bootstrap/issues/184) and they fixed it within two hours.

Amazed!

Deepak